# Oracle function overloading

Tags: oracle, function, exception

I have two tables: Bill:

```
Bill_Number (PK/FK),
Menu_Item_Number (PK/FK),
Discount,
Quantity_Sold,
Price.
```

And Item:

```
Item_Number (PK),
Item_Name,
Current_Price,
Production_Cost.
```

Now I want to create the function which will receive the Item_Number as the input and return the full `SUM(Quantity_Sold * Price)` and `SUM(Quantity_Sold*Price)` after discount.

In my exception, I want to handle NO_DATA_FOUND error if the Item_Number doesn't exist in Item table. I also want to return the message if the Item_Number exists but has never been sold. I used the NO_DATA_FOUND for the first case(Item_Number doesn't exist), so which one I have to use for the second case?

This is my code:

```
FUNCTION FN_Check
    (P_Item_Number NUMBER)
RETURN Varchar2
 IS  
V_Count Number (5,0);
V_Item_Number Number (5,0);
V_Output Varchar2 (500);
V_TotalDiscount Number (10,2);
V_CurrentTotal Number (10,2);
itemHasNotSold Exception;
Begin
Select Item_Number
Into V_Item_Number
From Menu_Item
Where Item_Number = P_Item_Number;

Select NVL(count(Item_Number),0)
INTO V_Count
From Bill
Where Menu_Item_Number = V_Menu_Item_Number;

If V_Count = 0 THEN
RAISE itemHasNotSold;
 ELSE
Select SUM(bi.Selling_Price*bi.Quantity_Sold - bi.Selling_Price*bi.Quantity_Sold*bi.Discount/100 ),
SUM(bi.QUANTITY_SOLD *mi.Current_Price) 
Into V_TotalWithDiscount, V_CurrentTotal
From Bill_Item bi, Menu_Item mi
Where bi.Item_Number = P_Item_Number and mi.Item_Number= bi.Item_Number;
V_Output := V_Menu_Item_Number || 'was sold total' || V_TotalWithDiscount || 'and the total should be' || V_CurrentTotal || 'with the current price';
 END IF;
  Return V_OutPut;
EXCEPTION

WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Menu Item Number does not exist');
RETURN V_Output;

When itemHasNotSold THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20002, 'Item has not sold');

WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20003, 'Data error.Please contact xxx-yyyyyyy for more infomation');
End FN_Check;
```

Comment: Your WHEN OTHERS clause is bad practice.  You suppress all the useful information in the real message and return a generic unhelpful message instead.  What's the application admin supposed to do with that?

Comment: Just a message for practice, I gonna modify it later

Comment: What does the modified code do that you don't want it to do?  What doesn't it do that you want it to do?  It's not obvious to me what your question is.  The fact that you aren't actually joining `bill_item` and `menu_item` in your query certainly appears problematic but since I don't now what problem you're trying to solve, I'm not sure whether that is the source of the error.

Comment: Actually, I have to check 2 cases in my function: 
_The Item_Number does not exist in Menu_Item table
_The Item_Number does not exist in Bill_Item table (that Item has never been sold)
_ If the input is not in those 2 cases: select SUM (bill.Price* bill.Quantity_Sold  - bill.Price* bill.Quantity_Sold* bill.Discount/100)
and SUM ( bill.Quanity_Sold * Menu_Item.Current_Price)
And I have the error in that SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

```
IF V_Total IS NULL THEN
RETURN 'Nothing sold yet';
END IF;
```

right after

```
Where Bill.Item_Number = V_Item_Number;
```

may work.

More precise would be to check the count(*) from bill where item..

Comment: or check exists (select 1 from bill where item..) :)

Comment: Next time just edit your original answer instead of deleting it and posting a second one.

Comment: Is there any way to handle those 2 things by exception section? I thinking about using the statement to select the Item.Item_Number and Bill.Item_Number together and handle them with NO_DATA_FOUND ,or like you said, select count(Item_Number) on 1 of those table. You think use select count() on Bill table or Item table is better?

Comment: You could extend your first select:  Select Item_Number
     Into V_Item_Number
     From Item
     Where Item_Number =P_Item_Number and exists(select 1 from Bill where Bill.Item_Number = P_Item_Number);

Comment: Not sure, btw, the count should never be null.

Answer (score 0):

I get it done by modified some typos in the #1 post. Thanks all.